# My Intention of this code is to send email if the product qty is less than zero or equal to zero but the email is not getting

Tags: python, mysql, email, flask

Friends

I have posted a Code below I have written the code as I want to send an email when the productqty = 0. Then an email should be sent to the admin. For this condition, I have fetched the value from the request form and stored it in the variable called ProductQty and I have used that variable in the " if " condition according to the when the condition becomes true the def function is called (email_alert) and the email should be sent to the prakprak2002@gmail but the email is not getting. Please if possible any suggestions or solutions to the problem.

thankyou and sorry about my bad English grammar.

```
@app.route('/editProduct',methods = ['POST'])
def editProduct():
   if request.method == 'POST' and 'ProductID' in request.form and 'NEWProductName' in request.form and 'NEWProductDescription' in request.form and 'NEWProductQty':
      try:
         productID = request.form['ProductID']
         productName = request.form['NEWProductName']
         productDescription=request.form['NEWProductDescription']
         ProductQty=request.form['NEWProductQty']
         cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute("UPDATE Products SET productName = % s,productDescription = % s, QTY = % s WHERE productID = % s",(productName,productDescription,ProductQty,productID) )
         msg = "Product Edited "
         mysql.connection.commit()
         cursor.close()
         if ProductQty <= 0:
             email_alert('prakprak2002@gmail.com')
      except:
         #con.rollback()
             msg = "error in operation"
      finally:
         return redirect(url_for('product', msg = msg))#+"?msg="+msg)
         #con.close()
```

The above code is the route.
The below code is the email_alert function.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
mail_content = ''' Hello,
This is a simple mail. There is only text, no attachments are there. The mail is sent.
Thankyou '''

#The mail addresses and password
def email_alert(receiver_address):
    sender_address = 'email'#intentionally wrote
    sender_pass = 'password'#intentionally wrote
    receiver_address = receiver_address
#Setup the MIME
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['From'] = sender_address
    message['to'] = receiver_address
    message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has an attachment.'
#The body and the attachments for the mail
    message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
    session.starttls() #enable security
    session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
    text = message.as_string()
    session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
    session.quit()
    print('Mail Sent')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using flask_mail extension for flask. You could send an E-Mail as easy as that:

```
from flask_mail import Message
from app import mail

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.html = html_body
    mail.send(msg)
```

You should also consider sending it as an Asynchronous call, since it can take a while. You can find detailled information on how it can be implemented under the following link:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xi-email-support

And please consider using SQL expression language, instead of raw SQL to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have not revealed how this is failing; I would assume that the problem is that Gmail rejects the connection because you failed to do the `ehlo()` again after `startls()`. (Yes, it's a bit crazy that they require this; but they do.)

Tangentially, you should probably update your `email` code to use the Python 3.6+ `EmailMessage` module.

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Don't put a space before the text. Fix typos.
mail_content = '''Hello,
This is a Simple mail. There is only text, no attachments are there. The mail is sent.
Thank you.'''

#The mail addresses and password
def email_alert(receiver_address):
    sender_address = 'email'
    sender_pass = 'password'
    # Comment out, utterly pointless
    # receiver_address = receiver_address

    message = EmailMessage()    
    message['From'] = sender_address
    message['to'] = receiver_address
    # Don't lie i the subject
    message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python. It has no attachment.'
    message.set_content(mail_content)

    # Use a context manager
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as session:
        # EHLO is required ... twice
        session.ehlo()
        session.starttls()
        session.ehlo()
        session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
        # Prefer send_message
        session.send_message(message)
    # Probably don't print anything
    print('Mail Sent')
```

Comment: hi, @triplee when I run the email alert python code separately by providing parameters the mail is sending but I want to send the email when there is a condition satisfied in the main program which I provided in the question. please refer to this video which I have recorded so you can get a clarify [link](https://youtu.be/zhAtpSsEVfg)